# Building the directory tree

Tags: clojure

I am trying to build a directory tree such as how xml trees are represented, in the form of a vector, i can traverse the file system fine using the following snippet but i can't put my head around how to build a tree structure out of this?

```
(defn trav [dir]
  (if (.isDirectory dir)
    (do
      (println (.getName dir))
      (doseq [file (.listFiles dir)]
        (if (.isDirectory file)
          (trav file)))      
      )))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
(defstruct file :file)
(defstruct dir :file :contents)

(defn file-tree
  [#^File file]
  (if (.isDirectory file)
    (struct dir file (vec (map file-tree (.listFiles file))))
    (struct file file)))
```

If you query the resulting map for `:file` you get the file entry for this node back. If you ask for `:contents` and get `nil`, it's a file. A vector indicates a directory.

As Carl already said: maybe `file-seq` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not really good at this either, but...

were you aware that there is already a "built in" function to turn a directory tree into a sequence?

See http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/file-seq .

Maybe this will meet your needs. Otherwise, we'll just wait until the really smart Clojurians show up.